# ¿Cómo puede un objeto cambiar su clase?

Tags: python, diseño-de-clases

Tengo dos clases que para fines de ejemplo llamare `Entero` y `Flotante`. Necesito un método para que un objeto cambie de clase por si mismo, sin intervención de código externo.

El resultado deseado está ilustrado por el siguiente pseudo-código:

```
class Entero:
    def __init__(self, valor: int):
        self.valor = valor

    def convertir_a_flotante(self):
        self.valor = float(self.valor)
        # Aqui cambiar la clase del objeto a Flotante.

class Flotante:
    def __init__(self, valor: float):
        self.valor = valor

    def convertir_a_entero(self):
        self.valor = int(self.valor)
        # Aqui cambiar la clase del objeto a Entero.

a = Entero(1)
print(f"Type(a) = {type(a)}") => Type(a) = <class '__main__.Entero'>
a.convertir_a_flotante()
print(f"Type(a) = {type(a)}") => Type(a) = <class '__main__.Flotante'>
```

La idea no es generar un nuevo objeto, sino conservar el existente, de modo que las referencias previas al objeto sigan siendo válidas.

#### Edición

Con la respuesta de CalumRakk y observaciones de Abulafia, hice una segunda versión para comprobar que el objeto *mutado* sea realmente de la nueva clase, implementando el método común `__str__`

```
class Entero:
    def __init__(self, valor: int):
        self.valor = valor

    def convertir_a_flotante(self):
        self.valor = float(self.valor)
        self.__class__=Flotante

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Entero {self.valor}"

class Flotante:
    def __init__(self, valor: float):
        self.valor = valor

    def convertir_a_entero(self):
        self.valor = int(self.valor)
        self.__class__=Entero

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Flotante {self.valor}"

a = Entero(1)
print(a, type(a))
a.convertir_a_flotante()
print(a, type(a))
```

que produce:

```
Entero 1 <class '__main__.Entero'>
Flotante 1.0 <class '__main__.Flotante'>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar la propiedad `__class__` para definir el tipo del objeto.

Todo el código te quedaría así:

```
class Entero:
    def __init__(self, valor: int):
        self.valor = valor

    def convertir_a_flotante(self):
        self.valor = float(self.valor)
        self.__class__=Flotante

class Flotante:
    def __init__(self, valor: float):
        self.valor = valor

    def convertir_a_entero(self):
        self.valor = int(self.valor)
        self.__class__=Entero

a = Entero(1)
print(type(a))
a.convertir_a_flotante()
print(type(a))
```

Comment: Hace falta mencionar que el __init__ no se ejecuta cuando se cambia la clase con esta tecnica.

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia @DanteS. Quizás estas viendo algo que yo no veo, por favor, podrías decirte ¿A que te refieres y por qué sientes que falta mencionar lo del init?

Comment: No tiene nada de malo tu respuesta. Solo quería resaltar ese detalle. Toda clase cuando se inicializa (por ejemplo Entero()) en algún momento llama a una función llamada __init__. Cuando cambias el tipo con __class__, esa función no se ejecuta. Nada mas eso.